# jQuery - Add a option box to a table row

Tags: jquery, html, html-select

I'm trying to change a contentEditable div of my table (in one td ) to let users select only between 2 possible values.

I thought that a good solution could be to change that div (onfocus) to an option box containing the values. I achieved this with the following code:

```
    var linkText = "<select><option value=1>Usuari</option><option value=5>Administrador</option></select>";
    $(this).html(linkText);
```

I get the option box displayed, but I'm not able to select another value from it (it shows only the first one "Usuari"). First, I thought that it was a problem of display, but I went through css to float that element and nothing happened.

I tried also in another way:

```
   var element2 = document.createElement("select");
   var option1 = document.createElement("option");
   option1.innerHTML = "Usuari";
   option1.value = "1";
   element2.add(option1, null);
   var option2 = document.createElement("option");
   option2.innerHTML = "Administrador";
   option2.value = "5";
   element2.add(option2, null);
```

but the result was the same. My last try has been to change the option box to radio buttons,  I got both options displayed in the td but I can't select the second value neither.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: That's weird. Try to specify the second option as selected like so: `<select><option value=1>Usuari</option><option value=5 selected='selected'>Administrador</option></select>`

Comment: Not working for me, I only get second value selected but can't change to first one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out what my problem was:

I was trying to replace the content in the editableContent div with the select box:

```
    <div id="select3" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" contenteditable="true">
         <select> 
            <option value="1">Usuari</option>
            <option value="5">Admin</option>
         </select>
    </div>
```

And that way I get the select box but not "selectable".

The solution is to change **contenteditable** to false first.

```
    <div id="select3" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" contenteditable="false">
         <select> 
            <option value="1">Usuari</option>
            <option value="5">Admin</option>
         </select>
    </div>
```

It works perfect right now.

Thanks to all the previous answers!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="select"></div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('<select />')
    .append($('<option />').val(1).text('User'))
    .append($('<option />').val(1).text('Admin'))
    .appendTo('#select');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z18j6hm7/1/